# jQuery UI datepicker loses functionality with 'birthday' datetype format

Tags: jquery-ui, symfony, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to add a 'format' attribute to my 'birthday' datetype for a form in my Symfony2 app. After I add it, I lose the datepicker functionality from jquery-ui (the datepicker doesn't load).

> dob.php

```
 ->add('dob', 'birthday', array(
                        'invalid_message'=>'<a href="#[redacted]" >Date of birth is not a valid date</a>',
                        'widget' => 'single_text',
                        'format' => 'MM/dd/yyyy',  // the line at fault
                        'label' => 'Birthday',
                        'years' => range(mindate,maxdate), // redacted
                        'error_bubbling' => 'true',
                        'data' => getcurrentDate(), // redacted
                        'attr' => array(
                            'class' => 'datePicker'
                        )
                    ))
```

> app.js

```
/* Show native datepicker when supported in browser else show jQuery's datepicker */
            if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
                var date = new Date();
                var thisYear = date.getFullYear();
                $('input[type=date]').datepicker({
                    // Consistent format with the HTML5 picker
                    defaultDate: new Date(thisYear - 18, 6 - 1, 15),
                    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                    yearRange: '-120:-10',
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true
                });
            }
```

Symfony version: 2.6.7
Jquery-UI version: 1.11.x

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the input type like this:

```
->add('dob', 'date', ...)
```

See [Symfony2 Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html)

Comment: That didn't work. Birthday is a date field type too. I came across this:
_If you want your field to be rendered as an HTML5 "date" field, you have to use a single_text widget with the yyyy-MM-dd format (the RFC 3339 format) which is the default value if you use the single_text widget._

Is there any alternative to get the format I need?

Comment: That created 3 input fields for each date type: month, day and year.

Comment: You may use http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html to transform your datetime property to date.